# how to add padding to actionscript 3 combo box dropdown

Tags: actionscript-3

i need to add a border to combo box drop down. as depicted in the attached picture.

1st picture when the items added as itemRenderer and it doesn't have padding.

i need to create a combo box dropDown as second pic(right hand side picture).

those small boxes are sprites.

[image: pic]

Comment: Do you use your own component(class) for combobox? It is not clear how your combobox dropdown menu gets constructed.

Comment: yes. i have seperate class which extends ComboBox

Comment: following tutorial helped me to achieve my task. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/07/18/setting-the-dropdown-menu-border-thickness-and-border-color-on-a-combobox-control-in-flex/